# CCRenderTexture crashed in child thread - "Could not attach texture to framebuffer"

Tags: c++, multithreading, cocos2d-x

```
cocos2d::CCTexture2D* texture = iSprite->getTexture();

CCRenderTexture* rt = CCRenderTexture::create(texture->getPixelsWide(), texture->getPixelsHigh());
```

Cocos2d: Assert failed: Could not attach texture to framebuffer

When I call CCRenderTexture in main thread - all ok. But If I try invoke CCRenderTexture from child thread i receive this assert.

How can I call this method in main thread? So, dispatch_async is not available in cocos 2d-x.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Cocos2D any code that creates or modifies textures has to be run on the main thread. This is a limitation of OpenGL, because attaching or detaching textures has to be done from the same thread the OpenGL context was created on. Normally that's the main thread.

In short: you can't create, render or take an image from CCRenderTexture on any thread other than the main thread.